# Adding Table Styling to New API Management Portal

Tags: css, azure, azure-api-management

I'm in the process of transition my client's Azure API Management portal implementation from the "legacy" portal to the new/current portal, using this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal-customize

For the most part, the transition has been easy except for the lack of ability to create custom styles and style sheets:

> **Styling**
>
> Although you don't need to adjust any styles, you may consider
> adjusting particular elements. For example, change the primary color
> to match your brand's color.

Many of our API pages have HTML tables in them that are used to describe the JSON messages that are submitted for PUT, POST, and PATCH operations.  Under the new API Management Portal, the table CSS is gone and I see now way to re-add a reference to our old style sheet.   The CSS formats the table borders, header row colors, etc., as shown in the sample below.

**Is there a way to add custom CSS to the "new" API Management portal?**

If not, how am I supposed to consistently format hundreds of tables across all of our existing documentation?   Embedding the CSS into every page seems like crazy-talk, but I don't see any other way to do it.

Here's an example of a table that my client has styled that is in the "Request Body" section of one of the APIs:

[image]

I see there's an [open ticket in the API Management's GitHub repo to add a "table widget"](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/931) which will be nice when it's available, but doesn't help me right now.

Answer (score 0):

In digging around in the existing styles already defined in the new portal, I found that if I add the following style to my table, it cleans-up pretty nicely:

```
<table class="table">
```

The table posted in my original post looks as follows with the `.table` style applied:

[image]